# Where should uploaded files get stored in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When user uploads files. In Rails 3.0+, these would go into public/uploads. In 3.1, should uploaded files go to app/assets/uploads? Or still in public/uploads?

It's not really an issue in our environment, since we are using S3. Just trying to understand Rails 3.1's new directory structure.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the public directory, capistrano recommends public/system/

don't get confused by the app/assets directory, it's usually for css/js/coffeescript files, think this is the biggest change from 3.0 to 3.1

Answer (score 3):

Well, the answer is simple: your users will only have access to your `/public` directory.

There are just some tricks to get `css` and `js` but you'll have to stick with `/public` for the other stuff.

Generally, I put all stuff in `/public/assets`

Answer (score 0):

adding on to apneadiving's answer:

if you use Carrierwave , the temporary files are in your system's /tmp directory and the uploaded files are in a subdirectory underneath $RAILS_ROOT/public , e.g. $RAILS_ROOT/public/uploads/YOUR-MODEL/...

In Rails 3.1 the 'assets' directory is meant for the JavaScript and CSS files so that sprockets can pick them  up there and so that they are *not* accessible directly via the "public" directory...

```
  see: assets/javascripts/application.js and assets/stylesheets/application.css  files
  see: http://railscasts.com/episodes/265-rails-3-1-overview
```

The app/assets directory is for CoffeeScript files (also not publicly accessible, so not a place to put uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Putting uploaded files in the filesystem only works if you have one file server or a network mapped storage... I usually just put the files in the database itself.

But as vrsmn said, don't use assets for this, assets pipeline is for streamlining the css/js/application images.